# What are the derivatives of position with respect to time

Tags: etymology

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jounce, the derivatives of position with respect to time are position, velocity, acceleration, jerk, snap, crackle, pop.

Who came up with snap, crackle, and pop?  What about higher order derivatives?

Comment: If you want to know what the 4th, etc derivatives of position mean and how they are used -- if ever -- as opposed merely to what they are called -- try the Physics SE.

Comment: Have you looked up the references in the footnotes to the Wikipedia article? That's *your* job; if there's a linguistic matter in those references that puzzles you, you may ask about that here.

Comment: [Suggestions for 4th order derivatives and above](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/General/jerk.html).

Comment: James Joyce did however coin the term Quark for a cream cheese derivative.

Comment: @Graffito This would be a forceful answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [wikipedia article you cited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jounce) gives a reference to [this summary](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/General/jerk.html) from [The Original Usenet Physics FAQ](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/), which states, "Needless to say, none of these are in any kind of standards, yet.  We just made them up on usenet."

Searching Google, I found [this usenet net.space thread from January 1984](http://www.megalextoria.com/forum2/index.php?t=msg&goto=63269&) in which [Bill Gosper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Gosper) wrote:

```
Message-ID: <15994@sri-arpa.UUCP>
Date: Thu, 26-Jan-84 06:28:00 EST
Article-I.D.: sri-arpa.15994
Posted: Thu Jan 26 06:28:00 1984
Date-Received: Sat, 28-Jan-84 03:19:55 EST
Lines: 9

From:  Bill Gosper 

Did you mean finesse instead of finess?  Objectation instead of oblectation?
Anyway, here are three more from hearsay:

Crackle:  see Snap.
Pop:  see Snap.
Snap, Crackle, and Pop:  the fourth, fifth, and sixth time derivatives of
position..
```

If you want to find out more about it, your new challenge is to find Bill Gosper and convince him to post an answer here.

Answer (score 3):

"Snap, crackle, pop" was (perhaps still is?) an advertising slogan for Kellogg's Rice Crispies, attempting to imitate the sound made when rice crispies encounter milk.

Comment: There is a long tradition in physics using quirky names, such as *strange, charm, wino*. Sounds like more of the same.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of reference.  I fail to see how this answer about Rice Crispies answers the OP's question.  Is Murray Gell Mann (who named the quark) responsible?  Or a Murray wanna-be? An answer needs a reference.

Comment: Really, this reference mania is getting out of hand.

Comment: The makers of Rice Crispies did  not write a paper proposing snap, crackle and pop as the 4,5,6th derivatives of position wrt to time, any more than James Joyce proposed quark as the name of the particles that make up hadrons.

Comment: @ab2 - You obviously don't understand Joyce's imagery and symbolism.

Comment: @Hot Licks  I know I don't!  Did gluons come from Joyce too?